# How to upload image to server with headers in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm Trying to upload image to server with headers Hope my code is fine but i don't know it cannot upload. My code is

```
{

    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type":@"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
                                   @"p-auth-token":self.token};

    NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ica.com/facilitator/server/v1/media"];

    UIImage *image= profile_Image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
    double my_time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(my_time)];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"", imageName, @".jpg\"\r\n\""];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];


    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSDictionary *statusDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        statusDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];


        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];




        NSLog(@"Images form server %@", statusDict);



    }] resume];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) with below code,

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"upload_url" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"upload_file_name" fileName:@"somefilename.jpg" mimeType:@"mime_type_of_file"] // you file to upload

    } error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
    uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
    progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    // This is not called back on the main queue.
    // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Update the progress view
    [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
    });
    }
    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
    }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: where should i give headers here? it gives Request failed: unauthorized (401) error.

Comment: Like this, [formData appendPartWithHeaders:@{@"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"} body:nil];
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"bytes" fileName:@"newimage.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];